# MPAndroidChart: Draw projection graph with left and right axis of different scale.

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

My requirement is to draw this graph which as you can see has left and right axis of different scales. Left axis starts at 0, and right starts at roughly £90k.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkd5t.png

I have tried setting axis dependencies:

```
p95Set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
p5Set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
```

That did not help draw vertical lines for some reason.

I have also tried reducing the number of line data entries from the front fo array. Also nothing.

Is there a particular setting that I haven't discovered yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting one axis as right:

```
p95Set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
p5Set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
```

Have you tried this. It should work because I used that. There should be another error. Also if it is ok please share your code too buddy.